# Open a custom litebox in Joomla 2.5/3.x from the toolbar within the component's backend

Tags: joomla, toolbar, backend

The Joomla 2.5/3.x API does not seem to support more than the JToolbarHelper::custom(X) methods to invoke custom tasks. In context of the component's backend, what is the best way to bring a custom litebox up just like JToolbarHelper::preferences() does?

Comment: What kind of content do you wish to put in the lightbox? Is it something contained in the document, a confirmation box or an iframe?

Comment: It should contain a custom dialog or form.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla! 3.x, the preferences view is no longer modal.

In Joomla 3 this can be done using a custom layout, as done in the Article Manager's `Batch` button.

The following piece of code:

```php
$bar = JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');

$layout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.toolbar.batch');

$dhtml = $layout->render(array('title' => $title));
$bar->appendButton('Custom', $dhtml, 'batch');
```

loads a layout that returns an HTML string:

```html
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#collapseModal" class="btn btn-small">
    <i class="icon-checkbox-partial" title="{$title}"></i>
    $title;
</button>
```

When clicked, it triggers the generation of a modal box which content will be taken from an element with the id `collapseModal`.

You may choose to provide `appendButton()` with your own HTML string.

You can generate the modal content in the view's template (the Article Manager does that in `/administrator/components/com_content/views/articles/tmpl/default_batch.php`).

I don't have Joomla! 2.5 installed at the moment (so I can't test the following suggestion), but you should be able to hook to the `Joomla.submitbutton` JavaScript method (don't forget to include the modal behavior).

You can override it in your template code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        var submitbuttom = Joomla.submitbutton;
        Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
        {
            if (task == 'mytask') {
                SqueezeBox.open('path/to/desired/view.php', {handler: 'iframe'});
            } else {
                return submitbutton.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
    })();
</script>
```

or have it use existing source via

```javascript
SqueezeBox.open($('myModalContainerId'), {handler: 'adopt'});
```

where `mytask` is the task that is provided to the toolbar helper:

```php
JToolbarHelper::addNew('mytask');
```

Comment: I have tried the apporach for J2.5. Overriding Joomla.submit of course requires an else branch containing the original submittbutton function, otherwise all other toolbar tasks won't work.

Comment: You are correct. I made an edit to my answer to include a better way to override an existing method in JS. Did it work for you in J!2.5?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I did't test the Joomla 3 approach yet.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 3.x is much simpler than that. I give you two simple choices, but you may want to go deeper, depending on the needs:

Choice 1:

```
JToolbarHelper::preview('index.php?option=com_option&view=yourview&tmpl=component');
```

Choice 2:

```
$bar = JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
$bar->appendButton( 'Popup', 'zoom-in', 'Preview', 'index.php?option=com_option&view=yourview&tmpl=component' );
```

As I said above, you may want to go deeper by overriding JToolbarButton. The main directions would be to create a file in /administrator/yourcomponent/toolbar/button/yourcustom.php. Then you would call this in your addtoolbar method:

```
$bar= JToolBar::getInstance( 'toolbar' );
$bar->addButtonPath(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/toolbar/button');
$bar->appendButton('Yourcustom', 'file', JText::_('Test'), 'yourtask', false);
```

Take a look at /libraries/cms/toolbar/button examples.